# ReactJS: After build project got "TypeError: n.render is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I run command npm run there are no any problems, but after npm run build and serve it I got in console error: "Uncaught TypeError: n.render is not a function"
My environments are:
Node: v12.13.0
npm: 6.12.0

I think it is because of my npm version is not compatible with reactjs version of project?

My files are below:

## package.json:

```
{
  "name": "material",
  "private": true,
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "main": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prettier": "prettier --write ./src/**/**/**/*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^2.0.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "downshift": "^2.1.1",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.14",
    "element-resize-event": "^2.0.9",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "~1.3.8",
    "material-ui-pickers": "1.0.0-rc.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.0-next.3e165448",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">0.25%",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-app-rewire-provide-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2"
  }
}
```

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import configureStore, { history } from './store/configureStore';
import Root from './components/Root';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Root store={store} history={history} />
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/Root', () => {
    const NewRoot = require('./components/Root').default;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
        <NewRoot store={store} history={history} />
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  });
}

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

## Root.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ScrollToTop from 'components/ScrollToTop';
import App from './App';

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
          </ScrollToTop>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Please, help. Thank you!

Comment: Here's something that might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930747/ios-release-build-crashes-typeerror-n-render-is-not-a-function-in-n-render

Comment: I have the error too, but this solution seems to work with react native.